# Phantomjs makes screencapture on mobilesite level and not full website

Tags: phantomjs, viewport

So very new to phantomjs and testing the screencapture feature, as this is the one I need. But it seems that the screencapture I make gets a capture of the mobile view of a webpage. I a page is responsive I get the view that would fit a mobile and not the full size I want. Is it possible to control this and request "fullsize"?

Comment: Please post your current screencapture taking phantomjs code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work using this code

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = {width: 1600, height: 1050};
page.open('http://elmah.io', function () {    
    page.render('elmah6.png');
    console.log('elamh6.png')
    phantom.exit();        
});
```

The issue was that I placed the viewportSize inside the open function.

I followed this example.

http://daker.me/2013/07/testing-your-responsive-design-with-phantomjs.html